# ionic 3 How can I get data via post

Tags: angular, post, ionic3

How can I get data via post. i need help please.
my code:

```
 getmapdetail(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.post(this.apiUrl, JSON.stringify({id:3})).subscribe(data =>{

        resolve(data);
      },err =>{
        console.log(err);
      });
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// considering this is in some service
getmapdetail(){
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, JSON.stringify({id:3})).map(data => data.json());
}

// inject that service in component
// call that service from component like this
this.service.getmapdetail().subscribe(data => {
    // do what ever you want with data
})
```

Comment: hi,I could not. i need help please.  How can I get data via post? i want id match data